# FireWatir and jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, cucumber, watir, firewatir

after using this excellent peace of software called FireWatir, I wonder if there is a way to integrate jQuery-selector-magic to my test.

My first attempt is to use firewatir's `js_eval()` method like this

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'firewatir'
f = FireWatir::Firefox.new
f.js_eval("alert(42);")
```

The only thing I get is a

> JsshSocket::JSReferenceError:  alert is not defined

which is kind of strange because other expressions like

```
f.js_eval("document.location.toString();")
```

Work like a charm!

Anyone with a hint?

Thanks and greets,

Joe

Comment: I would suggest that you post this to http://groups.google.com/group/watir-general/ too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay folks,

i got jQuery working with a lot of researching and I hope this will be help you out if you have similar problems:

```
firefox.js_eval("var target = getWindows()[0]; target.content.jQuery('#selector').toggle()")
```

What i had to do was to select the window I am working in explicitly and within its content jQuery is available and one is able to use all of its awesomeness! ;)

Greetings
Joe

Comment: Sweet!! So it seems to me that all the command get directly send to the JSSh session, not exactly to the DOM. That's neat. Maybe it will be more useful something like this `firefox.js_eval("var $ = getWindows()[0].content.jQuery")` (don't know if this will work) And the next command, just type them as normal jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use it like you would normally with a $ you need to wrap it in a function which will run it on the context of the widows document.

```
var win = new getWindows()[0].content;
var doc = browser.contentDocument;

$ = function(selector) {

  win.content.jQuery(selector, doc);

}
```

[chicago web design](http://www.edigitalstudios.com)

Answer (score 0):

From the [FireWatir Wiki](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/FireWatir+JSSh+Information):

> FireWatir translates code into a JavaScript equivalent, which is then transmitted to the JSSh server and executed against the DOM of the page loaded in the browser.

The `alert` function belongs to the `window` object of a browser, not the DOM of the page. So you can call an alert like `window.alert('hello dollly')`.

FireWatir creates a JSSh session, that sends your `js_eval` to the DOM, therefore unable to interact with the `window`.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer. With the help of the guys at the firewatir irc channel I was able to get alert running through using window.alert - but still the final goal, jQuery, remains unsolved :/ I'll update my post today.

Comment: No window.jQuery isn't working - but there is the workaround I posted as answer. Thanks for your help!